# rails fetch records with no has many relationship and ones with a condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I have a `HomeMaker` and `PerDateUnavailability` models. `HomeMaker` has_many `per_date_unavailabilities`. I want all home makers who don't have a record in per_date_unavailabilities and home makers who have record but not when the `per_date_unavailabilties.unavailable_date` = somedate

I usually do the first part when I want HomeMakers without a  PerDateUnavailability record using `HomeMaker.includes(:per_date_unavailabilities).where(per_date_unavailabilities: {id: nil})`

and the second part of the condition using `HomeMaker.joins(:per_date_unavailabilities).where.not(per_date_unavailabilities: {unavailable_date: Date.today})`

How do I mix these?

Comment: Why can't you just chain them `HomeMaker.joins(:per_date_unavailabilities).where.not(per_date_unavailabilities: {unavailable_date: Date.today}).where(per_date_unavailabilities: {id: nil})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sql you need is somewhat like this:

```sql
select a.*
  from home_makers a left join per_date_unavailabilities b
  on a.id = b.home_maker_id
  where b.home_maker_id is NULL
  or b.unavailable_date IS NOT ?;
```

Expressing the `or` clause is a little tough in ActiveRecord, and its best we don't fight it. (Edited after OP's comment)

```rb
HomeMaker.joins("LEFT JOIN per_date_unavailabilities on per_date_unavailabilities.home_maker_id = home_makers.id")
.where("per_date_unavailabilities.home_maker_id IS NULL OR per_date_unavailabilities.unavailable_date != ?", somedate)
```

Comment: This is what worked at last. `HomeMaker.joins("LEFT JOIN per_date_unavailabilities on per_date_unavailabilities.home_maker_id = home_makers.id").where("per_date_unavailabilities.home_maker_id IS NULL OR per_date_unavailabilities.unavailable_date != ?", some_date)` . Thanks for pointing me in the right direction :)